# Is there a way to disable transitions during zooming?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

When I zoom in on a page that uses CSS3's `transition` property on things such as width, height, padding, margin, etc., the elements will transition when you zoom in and out. Is there a way to disable this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/forestka/fPBjB/

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/forestka/8jBjk/2/

Answer (score 1):

In your transition property you specify `all`

you can do something like

```
 transition: opacity 1s ease;
```

notice here ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)) `transition-property` is used  while you used the *shorthand* version so you specified:

```
transition-property: all;
```

More specifically the left property is changed when you change zoom and this is the reason the transition is fired. Notice that when you use something like `font-size` there is no animation since it doesn't change on zoom.
You can bind the transition to an event like `ready` and fire it with javascript.

Comment: I usually don't use `all`; the same thing happens if you transition the `left` property (which I need to do.)

Comment: @ForestKa Improved my answer. Maybe it will help better then last time

Comment: It's not necessary that "left" doesn't move during zooming, and I wanted to know if there was any easy way to change this. There's no real reason for me to add dozens of lines of JS to prevent the minor effects of "left" transitioning while zooming, so I just left it the way it was. Thanks for the answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

check out this answer on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20549817/1985601

"It works by adding the transition css when you click the buttons, and when you zoom the browser window, it removes that css.

This works on Firefox and Chrome, but not IE. On Firefox, when you zoom, the transition continues as normal, and the zooming doesn't affect it. On Chrome, the transition fast-forwards to its final state."